# SQL - Using nested replace on numbers

Tags: mysql, sql, replace

I have a database with a column that contains a set of numbers. Each number is its own value and I would like to replace the number with the new value.

```
Current Value   New Value
    1               5
    2               3
    3               2
    4               1
  any other         0
```

The above should perform the fllowing example

```
Input       output
1142         5513
6741         0005
0613         0052
```

I have thought about using the following nested replace but if the original value is 3 then it will change to 2 following the above chart. It will then replace again to 2!

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(form,'1','5'),'2','3'),'3','2'),'4','1')
```

Anyone have an idea how I can achieve this?

Comment: You can do this using a stored procedure.  However, you cannot do this in a single query, unless you are using Version 8 and can use recursive CTEs.

Comment: Not sure if mysql has `@LEN` and `@SUBSTRING` but it could be done within a single query with these functions.

Comment: it has len https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysqlserver.asp?filename=trysql_func_sqlserver_len3 and also Substring https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysqlserver.asp?filename=trysql_func_sqlserver_substring

Comment: Whats your thought around it @MBijen

Comment: Had a idea so tried it out, won't work. Am still replacing the already edited 2. 
Whats the datatype of the column and are it all numbers?

Comment: The datatype was varchar but i have just pulled the numbers from it leaving JUST number now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do your specific question in a single query you can indeed nest the REPLACE() many times as below. By doing it in 2 phases you can make the `modified 2` an unique character so you know which you need to change to 3.

```
SELECT
REPLACE(    
    REPLACE(
        REPLACE(
            REPLACE(
                REPLACE(
                    REPLACE(
                        REPLACE(
                            REPLACE(
                                REPLACE(
                                    REPLACE(
                                        REPLACE(
                                            REPLACE(
                                                REPLACE(Input, '1','E')
                                            ,'2','C')
                                        ,'3','B')   
                                    ,'4','A')
                                , '5','0')
                            , '6','0')
                        , '7','0')
                    , '8','0')
                , '9','0')
            , 'A','1')
        , 'B','2')
    , 'C','3')
, 'E','5')
from NummerTest
```

Comment: Lovely way of thinking outside the box!  Thanks so much for your help - worked spot on!